# Bootstrap Carousel (Gap between Navbar and Carousel)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I started to work with the examples of http://getbootstrap.com.

The Example "Carousel" looks fine on the website, but after downloading bootstrap, coping the html-Document and inserting some Pictures, there is a gap between Navbar and Carousel.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap.css file, navbar class contains property margin-bottom set as 20px.

```
.navbar 
{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

You can override it in your implementation(inline style or yourexample.css) as

```
.navbar
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing

```
    .navbar
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

in mystyle.css solved the gap between carousel slider and navbar problem.

Thank you Neha

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nav {
  margin-top:-20;
}
```

It can solve my problem. So try this.